# User input numbers and assign them to different variables using loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, user-input

I tried my best to find it on different forums so excuse me if it is an easy one.

I want to take different inputs from the user and assign them to different variables.
Using split() we can only enter the inputs in one line.

```
w,x,y,z = (input('Enter the number :').split(','))
```

But how can we ask for inputs in different line and assign them to the variables without typing the input function again.

I want the same output as below code but without typing input function multiple times.

```
w= int(input('Enter the number :'))
x= int(input('Enter the number :'))
y= int(input('Enter the number :'))
z= int(input('Enter the number :'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be input 4 numbers to array and then assign them to variables. For example:

```py
numbers = [int(input("Enter the number : ")) for _ in range(4)]
w, x, y, z = numbers

print(f"{w=} {x=} {y=} {z=}")
```

Prints:

```
Enter the number : 2
Enter the number : 3
Enter the number : 4
Enter the number : 5
w=2 x=3 y=4 z=5
```

---

Or:

```py
w, x, y, z = [int(input("Enter the number : ")) for _ in range(4)]
```